# How to find max records for given range

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a set of given range `1-100`, `101-10001`. I want to find the max records for each range.

Input:

```
Distance Rate
10       5
25       200
50       300
1000     5
2000     2000
```

Output:

```
Distance Rate
50       300
2000     2000
```

I was thinking about
`select max(rate) from table group by` or other window function. Because this question is too close to other similar questions, I only found solutions for other similar questions like by given dates.

Ranges are from human input, but I can make create a table for it.

Comment: where are the ranges coming from? do you have them stored in a table?

Comment: @vkp Ranges are from human input, but I can create a table for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `group by`:

```
select (case when distance <= 100 then 'group 1'
             when distance <= 1000 then 'group 2'
             else '!?!'
        end) as range_group,
       max(rate)
from t
group by (case when distance <= 100 then 'group 1'
               when distance <= 1000 then 'group 2'
               else '!?!'
          end);
```

Comment: What if I want to calculate (rate - avg(rate)) for the range? Is it the same?

Comment: @JohnHass Yes, change `max(rate)` to `rate-avg(rate)`. Or add it to have both values.