# How to calculate (ate - avg(rate) for each range?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This is a follow up question for [How to find max records for given range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44789740/how-to-find-max-records-for-given-range)

I have several ranges from human input,  like `1-100`, `101-10001`. For each range, I want to calculate `rate - avg(rate for each range)`.

Input:

```
Distance Rate
10       5
25       200
50       300
1000     5
2000     2000
```

Output:

```
Distance rate - avg(rate for each range)
10       x
25       xx
50       xx
1000     xx
2000     xxx
```

Comment: Why doesn't your question include the ranges?

Comment: Is this sufficient? 'I have several ranges from human input, like 1-100, 101-10001'

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the ranges and then use window functions.  This is pretty easy:

```
select t.distance, t.rate, v.grp,
       (t.rate - avg(t.rate) over (partition by v.grp)) as deviation
from t outer apply
     (values (case when t.distance <= 100 then '1-100'
                   when t.distance <= 1000 then '101-1000'
                   else 'other'
              end)
     ) v(grp);
```